# What is the proper way to remove a file from a Git repo?

Tags: git, github

what is the proper way to remove a file from a git repository? I mean the file is already in the repository in the main branch.

Should I `cd` into the directory and use `git rm filename` ? or just `rm filename` straight?

```
$ cd myproject
$ git rm filename
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "filename has been removed"
$ git push
```

Comment: Ok thanks but if `git rm filename` does the `git add filename` automatically do I still need to `git commit` and `git push` manually?

Comment: You still have to add & commit & push afterwards. The removal won't add/commit automatically.

Comment: @costaparas: not true, you don't have to do `git add` manually after `git rm`

Comment: @arkadiusz oh oops, you're right (thanks). Only commit/push would be needed if using `git rm`.

Comment: @costaparas Thank you. For moving files, if I want to move a file from a folder to a different folder, do I need to use `git mv filename` or just `mv filename`?

Comment: That's the sample principle as the `rm`. Either is fine. But if you `git mv`, you don't have to `git add`. If you do regular `mv`, then `git add` would be necessary

Comment: In fact, this is also specified in the docs: "*The index is updated after successful completion, but the change must still be committed.*"